# Is that possible to show multisite main site products into child sites?

Tags: wordpress, multisite

I want to create a multisite project in which main site can create woocommerce project and also when we add products on main site. It will show in child sites also. I tried that doing but it wouldn't show. Is that possible in wordpress?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can switch to the main site and query whatever you want and then restore.
In your child site theme, you do the following:

```
$main_site_id = 1; //use your main site id
switch_to_blog( $main_site_id );
//write any code as if you are in your main website
restore_current_blog();
//use the data you fetched in your current child site.
```

**Note:** If you will write woocommerce related code. Make your that you install woocommerce plugin in your child site.